# Как задать размер текста с помощью окна настроек

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Создал экран настроек, в котором могу изменять размер текста на основном экране. Однако как сделать так, чтобы Android смог понять, откуда я беру значение размера и какое оно должно быть?

Comment: Вы экран настроек создавали с помощью мастера Android Studio (File/New/Activity/Settings Activity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Создайте файл с настройками (тут и будет хранится ваш размер шрифта и прочие атрибуты).
2. При старте вашего приложения установите размер шрифта, согласно значению из файла настроек.
3. В окне настроек обновите значение файла настроек и заставьте ваше приложение обновить все шрифты (вручную или перезапуск не знаю как там это у Вас происходит)

Также читайте о PreferenceActivity